# How to Output matches of two columns in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

I have two columns that look like this in an excel files:

```
Col1,col2
Bananas,Apes
Dogs,Bananas
Cats,null
Birds,null
Apes,null
```

I want the output to be:

```
New_col
Bananas,
Apes
```

So basically just output the matches of two columns. Is this possible using excel?

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Answer (score 1):

Use FILTER:

```
=FILTER(A2:A6,ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2:A6,B2:B6,0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Or the same, different: `=FILTER(A2:A6,COUNTIF(B2:B6,AS:A6))`

Comment: @P.b yup that works, but COUNTIF is much slower on larger datasets.  Just pointing out why I choose ISNUMBER(MATCH()) over COUNTIF.